# How does Terminating in response to springboard's termination affect my app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 making a game app in iOS 6+. I am currently not a member of apple development, at least not until i finish the game completely. Sometimes right after i quit the simulator i get a "Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination" message appear. I know it's a memory management issue but with ARC i don't deal with memory. Also does this have something to do with the size of my app? But i don't know it's size. One minute Xcode shows 40mb and the next it'll show 12mb or 20 mb and other mb's in between so i don't know. Lets say i publish the app in app store and don't fix this rare termination issue, how would that affect the user when using my app? How would i fix this termination message issue?

Comment: "... in response to SpringBoard's termination".  Does this message in your console only appear when you quit (i.e. command-Q) the simulator?  or is it a totally unexpected crash while you are running your app in the simulator?

Comment: Actually i should say that it only happens after i test the game for too long and then i quit the simulator and only then sometimes i get that termination message

Answer (score 0):

If you're quitting the simulator via command-Q, then a "`Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination`" message is actually proper (the simulating app is terminating before the simulator -- that app known internally to Apple engineers as SpringBoard -- terminates).

As for your memory worries, once you get the hang of Xcode, you should try running your app under Xcode Instruments and with the [Activity Monitor template](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/ActivityMonitorInstrument/ActivityMonitorInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011355-CH43-SW1) and/or the [Allocations template](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AllocationsInstrument/AllocationsInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011355-CH40-SW1).